# Extjs 4.1.1 Overridden setValue of NumberField throwing uncaught error

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to create a new amount field which extends number field. My goal is to format number entered in this new amount field in format `0,000,000.00`. To achieve this I have overridden `setValue` and `parseValue` methods number field. This is working as expected but I am seeing javascript error in console. I checked in Firefox and chrome and both seems to give different error. Error seems be thrown on line `me.callParent(v)` of `setValue` function. JSFiddle link for code is http://jsfiddle.net/sgondhale/g88gR/

Below is code as well

```
Ext.define('my.view.form.AmountField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.NumberField',
    alias: 'widget.my-amountfield',
    spinDownEnabled: false,
    spinUpEnabled: false,
    hideTrigger: true,
    baseChars: '0123456789.',
    decimalPrecision: 2,
    minValue: 0.1,
    maxValue: 9999999.99,
    emptyText: '0.00',
    maxLength: 12,
    enforceMaxLength: true,

    parseValue: function (value) {
        value = parseFloat(String(value).replace(this.decimalSeparator, ".").replace(/,/g, ""));
        return isNaN(value) ? '' : value;
    },

    setValue: function (v) {
        var me = this;
        console.log(v);
        v = typeof v == 'number' ? v : String(v).replace(this.decimalSeparator, ".").replace(/,/g, "");

        v = isNaN(v) ? '' : Ext.util.Format.number(this.fixPrecision(String(v)), "0,000,000.00");
        me.setRawValue(v);
        return me.callParent(v);
    }



});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'my-amountfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Amount'
    }]
});
```

Error details from Chrome is

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type ext-all.js:21

b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21

Ext.define.setValue fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:53

Ext.define.beforeBlur ext-all.js:21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, one should call `this.callParent(arguments)`, before applying any formatting and then call `this.setRawValue(value)`. Here is revised `setValue` code which is a correct way of doing it

```
 setValue: function (v) {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(v);
        v = typeof v == 'number' ? v : String(v).replace(this.decimalSeparator, ".").replace(/,/g, "");

        v = isNaN(v) ? '' : Ext.util.Format.number(this.fixPrecision(String(v)), "0,000,000.00");
        me.setRawValue(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you need to add an array in the `me.callParent` method, so you can use two options:

1. `me.callParent([v]);`
2. `arguments[0] = v; me.callParent(arguments);`

Or you can use the superclass method calling:

`me.superclass.setValue.call(me, v);`

Comment: This is correct, if I do this then there is no error thrown, but I want to apply format 0,000,000.00 to value entered and this doesn't works with your suggestion. In order to apply formatting I need to call parents setValue with formatted value as parameter, passing new value as  part of array doesn't seems to work

Comment: You should use first the `me.callParent([v])`; and only after that use the formatting

Comment: Or you can try the `this.superclass.setValue.call(this, v);` with this the superclass will have the formatted value